# permutation/2 returns no permutation

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, prolog-toplevel

## What is permutation/2 ?

As said in the `help(permutation).`:

The  predicate  `permutation/2`  is  primarily  intended to  generate  permutations.

That's what I want to use it for.

---

## How permutation/2 should work

This is the example given in the documentation: (Of course, the box around does not exist normally.)

```
 ____________________________________________________________________|                                                                          |
| ?- permutation([1,2], [X,Y]).                                      |
| X = 1, Y = 2 ;                                                     |
| X = 2, Y = 1 ;                                                     |
||false.____________________________________________________________ ||
```

---

## Reproducing the example (and several other examples)

When I try `permutation/2`, not the same happens: (any of these are run on my computer)

```
?- permutation([1,2],[X,Y]).
X = 1,
Y = 2 .

?- permutation([2,1],X).
X = [2, 1] .

?- permutation([1,2],[2,1]).
true .
```

As you can see, prolog doesn't return any permutation but the input itself.

- *Why* is this happening?
- And how to get all permutations?

---

## More details on my prolog version.

- On my Ubuntu/Linux computer
- I installed the package `swipl` just yesterday
- it tells me it's version: `threaded, 64 bits, version 7.4.2`

Comment: @ Asqiir my Prolog version SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 7.4.0-rc1).Windows 7. it works as prescribed....

Comment: Look very closely at the transscript! There, it reads `X = [2, 1 ]**SPACE**.`. You have stopped Prolog from giving the next answer. Try to press `;` or `SPACE` instead.

Comment: The interpreter is basically asking you if you are happy with the answer. By pressing enter or `.`, you are saying "I am happy" and Prolog doesn't do anything else. If you press `;` or space, you are saying "no, this isn't it" and Prolog will then backtrack and give you another result.

Comment: If you want all of them in a list, you can do `setof(X,permutation([1,2,3],X),Xs).`.